# What is the probability that a random walk forms (almost) a circle?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, stochastic-processes, randomness

Given is a [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) of a particle in 3d (such as an atom in a liquid).
The particle proceeds randomly (in 3d), with an average straight displacement length a.

Is there a way to get a probability that the particle comes (almost) back to its starting point (in 3d space), by making a large circle? Here is a way to quantify the question.

What is the probability that the particle path forms a "closed/circular" path with average radius $R\gg a$, where the "circle" has not to be closed perfectly; start and endpoints can be at a distance $d$, with $R\gg d\gg a$.

Is there a way to get a rough estimate for this probability?

Comment: I would ask this on math stackexchange for a better response

Comment: OK -  I will try.